# JavaFX: Perspective camera on custom widget

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I am trying to create a "custom widget" (`extends HBox`) which renders 3D graphics.

The problem is that all the examples I see for setting the camera, show how to do it on the main "scene", which belongs to the main window.

I don't want any relation to the main Window, I want it to be an independent widget.

Is it anyway possible to do that?

I'll be glad if you can share some code example, as I feel pretty lost with it...

Comment: I've never tried this, but try wrapping your content in a [`SubScene`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html). You can set a camera of your choosing on the `SubScene`, and client code can add it to any other scene graph.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want the camera to be transformable, you can insert it into the Scene Graph where ever you want. You can add it to a group node like this:

```
Group someGroup = new Group();
PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
someGroup.getChildren().add(camera);

Scene s = new Scene(someGroup);
s.setCamera(camera);
```

When you now move the Group node the camera moves as well. You can add the camera to any Group node you want, but I am not sure what happens when you put it into a Group node that uses LayoutManagement like HBox.

The important thing is you always have to add the camera to the Scene that it is in.